# Three Cases Positive Prime Numbers in $\mathbb Z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the first $3$ positive prime numbers $d$ in $\mathbb Z$ such that the quadratic integers in $Q[\sqrt{d}]$ are precisely the ones of the form $a + b\sqrt{d}$, in which $a$ and $b$ are rational integers. Additionally, what would be the first $3$ positive prime numbers $d$ so that the quadratic integers in $Q[\sqrt{d}]$ are precisely the ones of the form $\frac{(a + b\sqrt{d})}{2}$, where $a$ and $b$ are rational integers and $a$ and $b$ are either both even or both odd. Also what would be the case when $\sqrt{d}$ is replaced by $\sqrt{−d}$.

Comment: If $d$ is squarefree, do you know what the integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ are?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes I remember that/

Comment: This may or may not be relevant to your question: http://oeis.org/A218459

Comment: @Anthony I think thats different.

Comment: @Rachel I guess it wasn't relevant. Oh well.